# Divergence of $\frac{1}{r^2} \textbf{e}_r$ on $\mathbb{R}^3-0$ is zero?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

Divergence of $\frac{1}{r^2} \textbf{e}_r$ on $\mathbb{R}^3-0$ is zero?

Can somebody help me with this calculation? Working in spherical coordinates here. It seems weird to me that this is true, since the flux through any smal parallelpiped would be stronger on the side closer to the origin. Yet this seems to be obvious in the text I'm reading, Arnold's "Mathmatical Methods in Classical Mechanics" chapter 36.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem here is that $\frac{1}{r^{2}}\bf{e}_{r}$ is not diferentiable at the origin. That's why the divergence outside the origin is zero but the integral is not.

Comment: If you have a small cube which doesn't contain the origin and oriented so that two of the sides are orthogonal to $\mathbf e_r$ at their midpoint, then yes, the flux into the side closest to the origin is larger than the flux out of the opposite side. However, there will also be a small flux out of the four remaining sides, and this turns out to exactly balance the discrepancy.